# Insert tab in between tabs in javafx tabpane

Tags: java, javafx, tabs

I am looking for the equivalent of this swing code:

```
tabPane.insertTab(String var1, Icon var2, Component var3, String var4, int var5);
```

in javafx.

I want to insert a tab in between tabs in tab pane.

Help me plz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just modify the `tabs` list according to your needs:

```
String tabTitle = "tab title";
Node tabContent = ...; // tab content goes here
int index = ...; // index for new tab

Tab tab = new Tab(tabTitle, tabContent);
tabPane.getTabs().add(index, tab);
```